# How to input a default value in {{ form.label }}

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am trying to develop my flask blog, and in `register.html`, I want to set a help register message. For example, when the user clicks on the username form, it can indicate "it must be 3-15 characters long"; or set a default value in the form, when the user clicks it, it would disappear.
But I don't know how to achieve it in `{{form.username.label}}` here's my original code:

```
    <fieldset class="form-group">
          <legend class="form-title" style="font-weight: 700;">Register</legend>
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>{{ form.username.label }} {{ form.username }}
            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
            <span style="color: orange;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}</p>
          </div>
```

Comment: I do not understand the problem. I am assuming you want to display "username" in ```form.username.label```.

Answer (score 0):

in your html:

```
{{form.label | default("label") }}
```